# Hide or remove or disable delete button in sharepoint 2013

Tags: branding, customization

how to hide or remove or disable delete item  button on sharepoint list.( Except transform permissions)
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the context of [this](http://sharepointism.blogspot.com.au/2008/05/hiding-context-menu-item-of-document.html) article you need to overwrite the `CAMopt` JavaScript method in `Core.JS` using the following:

```
function CAMOpt(p,wzText,wzAct,wzISrc,wzIAlt,wzISeq,wzDesc)
{
     var mo=CMOpt(wzText,wzAct,wzISrc,wzIAlt,wzISeq,wzDesc);

     if(!mo)return null;

     if(wzText != "Delete Item") AChld(p,mo);
     return mo;
}
```

I found an article that shows a method to do this in PowerShell as well ([available here](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2008/08/add-sharepoint-list-item-context-menu.html)) but I think this is less than ideal and would recommend the above approach.

Comment: According to this  [link](https://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/customize-or-override-core-js-file-functions-in-sharepoint/) .Overriding core.js . But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it´s just for this list you can use a custom CSS.

`<style>#ID_DeleteDocItem{
    display:none;}
</style>`

But it will only apply where the CSS is active and would affect every user.